# Installing packages but still python interpreter doesn't recognize using pycharm

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, pytorch

I'm trying to install pytorch, but when I'm trying to import, my pycharm doesn't recognize this package although I'm sure I've installed this package on the same interpreter.

[image]

What I am missing?!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you try restarting pycharm after the installation

Comment: You might want to consider upgrading your Python... 3.6.0 is almost 2 years old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are installing the packages in your base interpreter i.e your system interpreter. And I guess you started your Pycharm project using a virtual environment. So to install to your Pycharm venv. You need to start the console below i.e The Terminal in your Pycharm project and then perform `pip install package_name` again. This should install it to your virtual env. And then python will pick it up.

If you want to have all base packages from your system into your Pycharm venv. You can check the *inherit base packages* option while you are starting a new project with a new virtual env.

Comment: Oh right. Any chance the interpreter might be different ?

Comment: Not unless there is more than one Python 3.6 on the machine

Comment: Yeah, So maybe the interpreter that cmd, pycharm are picking up are different ?

Comment: Actually I was under venv, I need to learn further about that thing :/, Thanks a lot!!! installing through pycharm terminal

Comment: virtual environment is like a closed sandbox. It has no relation with it's outside python environment. So you have to reinstall packages into it again or you can inherit all packages which are already in the base system. And yea it's very useful as you start to use more and more versions of same packages.